# Removed Facebook SDK, still shows up in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

So in my ionic cordova project, I used the Facebook SDK in the past.  I decided to remove the Facebook plugin completely, yet it is still trying to build with it when I try to run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

I have completely deleted the plugin from the plugins directory

I have removed everything related to facebook from package.json and config.xml

Yet Facebook is still added to the AndroidManifest.xml and won't build.

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app.haywire.weekend",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 --stack-size=1968 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "4.4.6",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.4",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "android-versions": "^1.4.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "bower": "^1.8.4",
    "build": "0.1.4",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge.git",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.2.1",
    "firebase": "^5.5.9",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "4.4.6",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-support-google-services": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="app.haywire.weekend" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Haywire Weekend!</name>
    <description>The BEST Weekend of Your Life.</description>
    <author email="info@haywireweekend.com" href="http://haywireweekend.com/">Haywire Weekend Dev Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-hdpi/notification_icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-mdpi/notification_icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xhdpi/notification_icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxhdpi/notification_icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxxhdpi/notification_icon.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <config-file parent="./application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="~2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="~1.1.19" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.2:8100" sessionid="6732c993" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.11:8100" sessionid="ab577d24" />
    <plugin name="cordova-support-google-services" spec="cordova-support-google-services" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="2.0.5" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.12:8100" sessionid="5b08a392" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.10:8100" sessionid="d93425ac" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.17:8100" sessionid="33e8bf77" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.8:8100" sessionid="eb62deac" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.22:8100" sessionid="df904f92" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

And when I try to build I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 4s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\Michael\workspace\testing\haywire-weekend-repo\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:91: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka app.haywire.weekend:string/fb_app_id) not found.

C:\Users\Michael\workspace\testing\haywire-weekend-repo\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:94: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka app.haywire.weekend:string/fb_app_name) not found.

C:\Users\Michael\workspace\testing\haywire-weekend-repo\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:98: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka app.haywire.weekend:string/fb_app_name) not found.

C:\Users\Michael\workspace\testing\haywire-weekend-repo\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:91: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka app.haywire.weekend:string/fb_app_id) not found.
C:\Users\Michael\workspace\testing\haywire-weekend-repo\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:94: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka app.haywire.weekend:string/fb_app_name) not found.
C:\Users\Michael\workspace\testing\haywire-weekend-repo\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:98: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka app.haywire.weekend:string/fb_app_name) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

Comment: Good idea to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by removing platforms/android and rebuilding

`rm -rf platforms/android`

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`